# what is gpt-1 optimization method?

Tags: nlp

I'm reviewing the paper <Improving Language Understanding by Generative Pre-Training(2018)>.
The concept is well understood, but there is a question about the optimization method used in the paper.

[SGD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrjYL.png)

[Adam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0gyb.png)

In the first image, it looked like SGD was used for pre-training, but the second image showed that Adam was used. I'm posting a question because I think I might have misunderstood the concept!

I think they used Adam, but I wonder where SGD was used for.